# want to create new thread in android studio kotlin for setOnItemClickListener on listview to open new activity by taking data from database

Tags: multithreading, android-studio, kotlin, android-asynctask, kotlin-coroutines

want to create new thread in android studio kotlin  for setOnItemClickListener on listview to open a new activity  by taking data from database .
i am doing this on main thread which making my app freeze and also some times it is taking more than 2, 3 clicks on list item to open respective activity of item that i clicked.

```
package com.example.countriescapitals_continentwise

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.AsyncTask
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.PrecomputedText
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ListView
import android.widget.ProgressBar
import android.widget.SearchView
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import javax.xml.transform.Result

// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private const val ARG_PARAM1 = "param1"
private const val ARG_PARAM2 = "param2"

/**
 * A simple [Fragment] subclass.
 * Use the [AsiaFrag.newInstance] factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
class AsiaFrag : Fragment() {
    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private var param1: String? = null
    private var param2: String? = null
    private var  asyncTask:AsyncTask<PrecomputedText.Params,ProgressBar,Result>?=null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val asiaLayout= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_asia, container, false)

        val mAsiaLv:ListView=asiaLayout.findViewById(R.id.asialv_id)

        val msearchvw:androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView=asiaLayout.findViewById(R.id.asiasearchid)
        msearchvw.queryHint="Search Among Countries"
        msearchvw.isIconified=false





        val dbHelper=AssetOpenHelper(requireActivity())
        val dataBase=dbHelper.readableDatabase
        var myCursor=dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM ASIA",null)

        val mCursorAdapter=CustomCursorAdapter(requireContext(),myCursor)
        mAsiaLv.adapter=mCursorAdapter



        //on item click listner go to other activity
     mAsiaLv.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id->


         var mcountryName=myCursor?.getString(1)
         var mcapitalName=myCursor?.getString(2)
         var mcurrencyName=myCursor?.getString(3)
         var mlanguageName=myCursor?.getString(4)
         var mareaName=myCursor?.getString(6)
         var mpopulation=myCursor?.getString(5)
         var mimageName=myCursor?.getString(7)

         val intentToDetails= Intent(requireContext(),CountryDetails::class.java)
            intentToDetails.putExtra("icountryName",mcountryName)
            intentToDetails.putExtra("icapitalName",mcapitalName)
            intentToDetails.putExtra("icurrencyName",mcurrencyName)
            intentToDetails.putExtra("ilanguageName",mlanguageName)
            intentToDetails.putExtra("iareaName",mareaName)
            intentToDetails.putExtra("ipopulation",mpopulation)
            intentToDetails.putExtra("iimageName",mimageName)

            startActivity(intentToDetails)

        }

        // code for search view to search among listview items
        msearchvw.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener,
            androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(p0: String?): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            override fun onQueryTextChange(p0: String?): Boolean {

                myCursor=dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM ASIA WHERE COUNTRY LIKE '%${p0}%' OR CAPITAL LIKE '${p0}'",null )
                mCursorAdapter.changeCursor(myCursor)
                return false
            }

        }
        )



        return asiaLayout
    }

    companion object {
        /**
         * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
         * this fragment using the provided parameters.
         *
         * @param param1 Parameter 1.
         * @param param2 Parameter 2.
         * @return A new instance of fragment AsiaFrag.
         */
        // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
            AsiaFrag().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1)
                    putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2)
                }
            }
    }




}
```

///////////////// this is my xml file

<

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".AsiaFrag">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
    android:id="@+id/asiasearchid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

 <ListView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:id="@+id/asialv_id"/>
</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

/////////////// sqlite data base open helper

```
package com.example.countriescapitals_continentwise

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Context
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper
import android.util.Log
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileOutputStream

/// creating constants
const val dbName = "COUNTRY_DETAILS.db"
const val dbVersionNumber = 1

class AssetOpenHelper(private val context: Context):SQLiteOpenHelper(context,dbName,null, dbVersionNumber) {

    private var dataBase:SQLiteDatabase?=null

    init {
        // Check if the database already copied to the device.
        val dbExist = checkDatabase()
        if (dbExist) {
            // if already copied then don't do anything.
            Log.e("-----", "Database exist")
        } else {
            // else copy the database to the device.
            Log.e("-----", "Database doesn't exist")
            createDatabase()
        }
    }

    private fun createDatabase() {
        copyDatabase()
    }

    private fun checkDatabase(): Boolean {
        val dbFile = File(context.getDatabasePath(dbName).path)
        return dbFile.exists()
    }


    private fun copyDatabase() {

        val inputStream = context.assets.open("databases/$dbName")
        val outputFile = File(context.getDatabasePath(dbName).path)
        val outputStream = FileOutputStream(outputFile)

        val bytesCopied = inputStream.copyTo(outputStream)
        Log.e("bytesCopied", "$bytesCopied")

        inputStream.close()
        outputStream.flush()
        outputStream.close()
    }

    // Open the database with read and write access mode.
    private fun openDatabase() {
        dataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(context.getDatabasePath(dbName).path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE)
    }

    // Close the database.
    override fun close() {
        dataBase?.close()
        super.close()
    }



    override fun onCreate(p0: SQLiteDatabase?) {

    }

    override fun onUpgrade(p0: SQLiteDatabase?, p1: Int, p2: Int) {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never do Database operation in main thread.

always create a separate function for database operations.
Use loader to prevent user from clicking multiple times.

```
    viewModelScope.launch(){
                dbOperations()
            }

    private suspend fun dbOperations() {
       //Do your db task here. its background thread
            withContext(Dispatchers. Main) {

              //call next activity here. it is main thread.
    
            }
        }
```